# Logitech Master MX 2S app specific settings

Tags: 16.04, mouse, logitech, xbindkeys

So I have gone through almost all Master MX 2S questions here on Ask Ubuntu and other sites.

I did figure out how to do the xbindkeys for custom actions for some buttons and some synthetic key presses.

What I want to know is

1. If there is a way to do app specific settings for the mouse.
2. Using the thumb button as gesture button ( for example to move workspaces, etc )

libinputgestures is a fantastic project for multi-touch on track-pads . I was wondering if there is any , and if not , could anyone help me create one for the MX Master. I need help because I do not fully understand yet how these scripts are to be made but with some help I can definitely get started and find my way.

So please let me know if,

1. Anyone knows the answers to the 2 above features , or
2. Would like to help in creating a libinputgestures like utility for MX master. ( I know solaar btw. it doesn't let me do the mapping yet. So yeah )

Answer (score 0):

I tried using https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures
on my laptop,but it did not fix my touchpad anyway,
so I got message "libinput helper tools do not seem to be installed?"

I looked at /etc/libinput-gestures.conf file and you can try to add your device
mouse if you find it by command :

libinput list-devices

  I am not sure if that answers your question, but this project maybe is not for your device.